# Is there a way to force HTML to open an mp3 in the OS?

Tags: html, cross-browser, operating-system, mp3, client-side

Is there a cross-browser way of forcing something like:

```
<a href = "/mp3s/qwerty.mp3">Click to Listen or Download</a>
```

...to open in the *operating system*, and ***not*** in a browser plug-in (i.e. Quicktime)? I want the example link above to always show the OS dialog window: "`Open With... Save As...`".

---

Is this maybe possible with Javascript, or with the `ActiveXObject` for Windows OS at least?

---

Comment: No. You need some PHP to send some specific headers

Comment: (Or other server-side scripting language...)

Comment: will this be possible with HTML5?

Comment: Thanks guys for the information, unfortunately I cannot manipulate the HTML headers where I am at, nor can I use HTML5 as there is a strict need to support all possible browser types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% foolproof will-always-work way to do this, since the browser can always decide how to handle this in the end.

However, most sites that want to force a download, toy with the headers: send the mp3 file with `Content-disposition: attachment` or `Content-type: application/octet-stream`. This will suggest to the browser to offer to store the file as an attachment, and not show it internally.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Konerak, but do you know of any client-side alternative? Or might it be possible to manipulate the headers via client-side Javascript? I unfortunately do not have access to the server of the site I am working on...

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding the HTTP header

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

when qwerty.mp3 is requested. Can't tell you exactly how without knowing what HTTP server you are using.

Details in [RFC2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used it. But perhaps this is what is best for you.

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp

Again haven't tried it. And this is HTML5. Let us know what you find out.